# Performance issue in SSRS Report in Test Server?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportingservices-2005

I have query it contains 45,611 rows which executes in SSMS (Sql Server Management Studio) 2008 R2 in 2 sec.

In SSRS ,When i preview the report it will takes 6 sec,

After i deployed the same report and configure ASP.Net application here also it will takes same as 6 sec.

Next I published report in Test Server (same no of records),here it will takes more time like 30 sec .

See Here My Report is DrilDown in Chart Reports

How will i do to improve the performance ?

Answer (score 0):

Because, While you browse Report from SSRS, SSRS Reports needs to be Fetched into HTML that why it is taking extra time.

What i want to Suggest you is that : [Im supposing you are using ASP.NET]

You can Request the Report from Report Server.
Then, You can give the Output as an PDF Document.

Which will save the Time for Record Fetching (a Huge Table) as an HTML Table.

Hope You understand.

Comment: @Subedi,How can i give output as PDF format?Please Can you explain me step by step of How to do?am new to SSRS